# Laravel database query for specific date

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Please help guys. I have my database:

[image]

Moreless...

I want to build a query that will count each column with a specific date for a specific page. For example Page 1 have visits 25th Dec and 26th Dec, but I want count every visit on 26th.

Somebody could help me even with pure MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you how many visitors does a specific page has on specific date. I am not sure if this is what you aim for but that's what I understood from the question.

```
SELECT DATE(created_at) AS date_visited, page_id, COUNT(1) AS visits
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY DATE(created_at), page_id
```

As explanation - it is a basic GROUP BY usage, you can refer to the MySQL documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html if you are not familiar with these. It has nothing to do with Laravel tho.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `whereDate` and `groupBy` as:

```
Model::select('*', DB::raw('count(*) as count'))
    ->whereDate('created_at', '=', '2016-12-26')
    ->groupBy('page_id')
    ->get();
```

Or you can also use query builder as:

```
DB::table('table_name')
    ->select('*', DB::raw('count(*) as count'))
    ->whereDate('created_at', '=', '2016-12-26')
    ->groupBy('page_id')
    ->get();
```